# Equally sized column widths using tabular*

Tags: tables, minipage

I'm using a Springer template, so trying not to add add packages, however, I'm struggling to equally size the column widths. As shown in the image, the final three column widths seem unequal, and I'm not sure what is causing this, or how I might remedy this.

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{program}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\caption{Estimates of the noise standard deviation, and the corresponding reduction in velocity variance, once adjusted for noise, as a function of elevation from the channel bed. Dataset: $\boldsymbol{U_{0}}$ = 0.58 m/s; measurement location = (5, 0, $z$); ADV sampling period per coordinate = 5 min.}
\label{tab:noise_floor_as_a_function_elevation_0211-0215}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccccc}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{z [m]}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Noise standard deviation [ms$^{-1}$]}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variance reduction due to noise [\%]} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & $u$ & $v$ & $w$ & $u$ & $v$ & $w$ \\
\midrule
0.400   & 9.7e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 53.2  &   77.8  &  20.5  \\
0.300   & 1.1e$^{-2}$  & 1.1e$^{-2}$   & 2.5e$^{-3}$   & 63.9  &   84.1  &  27.9  \\
0.200   & 9.3e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.1e$^{-3}$   & 59.9  &   83.8  &  24.2  \\
0.100   & 9.5e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.1e$^{-3}$   & 59.0  &   76.5  &  20.9  \\
0     & 9.9e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 60.6  &   80.0  &  21.4  \\
-0.100  & 9.3e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.1e$^{-3}$   & 53.3  &   78.0  &  19.9  \\
-0.200  & 9.6e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 50.3  &   73.4  &  16.8  \\
-0.300  & 9.9e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 51.5  &   59.8  &  13.6  \\
-0.385  & 9.7e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 53.2  &   66.0  &  16.8  \\
\botrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table, called MWE: Minimal Working Example, that we can simply test it and than help you. Help us to help you!

Comment: BTW, with your code fragment I can't reproduce showed table. Please clarify, what is your problem.

Comment: Ok I've added a short preamble to the code. The problem is that the three rightmost columns are not equal. Ideally, all columns would have the same width.

Comment: Sorry, where is added preamble? It start with `\documentclass` and end with `\begin{document}` ... I don't see anything like this. Regarding changes question title, you may consider to use `tabularx` table.

Comment: ok, thanks for the guidance, however, I'm working with a pre-defined journal template, and I'm reluctant to add more packages, like tabularx. Hopefully my preamble is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You may liked:

[image]

**Edit:**
Original MWE is now extended with preamble which OP show in question. Preamble is wee bit changed since packages `amsmath` and `booktabs` are now loadead as `tblr` libraries, as already stated in original answer (dee sentence below). Result is the same as before.

With use of the `tabularray` package with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx` (which loads packages of the same name):

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{%amsmath,       % <--- moved to tblr library
            amssymb,
            %amsfonts,      % <--- loaded by amssymb
            amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{manyfoot}
%\usepackage{booktabs}      % <--- moved to tblr library
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% new, some packages are moved here as tblr library
\usepackage{tabularray}     % <--- new
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, 
                siunitx}    % <--- new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \sisetup{tight-spacing}
    \caption{Estimates of the noise standard deviation, and the corresponding reduction in velocity variance, once adjusted for noise, as a function of elevation from the channel bed. Dataset: $\bm{U}_0 = \qty{0.58}{\meter\per\second}/s$; measurement location: (5, 0, $z$); ADV sampling period per coordinate: \qty{5}{\minute}.}
    \label{tab:noise_floor_as_a_function_elevation_0211-0215}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} X[c, si={table-format=-1.3}]
                        *{3}{X[c, si={table-format= 1.1e1}]}
                        *{3}{X[c, si={table-format= 2.2}]}
                       },
             row{1,2}= {guard},
             row{2}  = {mode=math}  
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    z [m] 
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Noise standard deviation [\unit{\meter\per\second}]
        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    Variance reduction due to noise [\%] 
                    &   &       \\
    \cmidrule[r]{2-4} \cmidrule[l]{5-7}
    & u & v & w & u & v & w     \\
    \midrule
0.400   & 9.7e-3    & 1.0e-2    & 2.2e-3    & 53.2  & 77.8  & 20.5  \\
    \bottomrule
0.300   & 1.1e-2    & 1.1e-2    & 2.5e-3    & 63.9  & 84.1  & 27.9  \\
0.200   & 9.3e-3    & 1.0e-2    & 2.1e-3    & 59.9  & 83.8  & 24.2  \\
0.100   & 9.5e-3    & 1.0e-2    & 2.1e-3    & 59.0  & 76.5  & 20.9  \\
0       & 9.9e-3    & 1.0e-2    & 2.2e-3    & 60.6  & 80.0  & 21.4  \\
-0.100  & 9.3e-3    & 1.0e-2    & 2.1e-3    & 53.3  & 78.0  & 19.9  \\
-0.200  & 9.6e-3    & 1.0e-2    & 2.2e-3    & 50.3  & 73.4  & 16.8  \\
-0.300  & 9.9e-3    & 1.0e-2    & 2.2e-3    & 51.5  & 59.8  & 13.6  \\
-0.385  & 9.7e-3    & 1.0e-2    & 2.2e-3    & 53.2  & 66.0  & 16.8  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** in the case that you prefer to have exponent numbers in form `e^{-...}`, than you only need to change column specification of the first column group, i.e. table preamble is:

```
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{}  X[c, si={table-format=-1.3,
                                      minimum-decimal-digits=3}]
                        *{3}{X[c, si={table-format= 1.1e1,
                                      exponent-product = {},        % <---
                                      exponent-base = \mathrm{e}}]} % <---
                        *{3}{X[c, si={table-format= 2.2}]}
                       },
             row{1,2}= {guard},
             row{2}  = {mode=math}  
             }
```

an table than become:

[image]

Comment: thank you for this, but the document will not compile when I copy your code. There are too many errors. I tried your code on a blank template, and the code worked, so I suspect there may be conflicts with other packages that I have, but I'm unable to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @eg0u30a2, I tested my proposition with preamble which you show in figure. No errors.  That you will be able to confirm my claims, I add your preamble to my MWE.

Comment: is there another way to do this without amending the list of packages in the preamble? I would only like to use the tabular package if possible

Comment: It's a pity because `tabularray` is likely to become a standard because its interface is so intuitive

Comment: Of course are other ways too, but to my opinion no so elegant/simple. Apparently will wait on other answer ... good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As a minimal invasive change to make your columns equally spaced, you could use fixed width columns:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{program}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\caption{Estimates of the noise standard deviation, and the corresponding reduction in velocity variance, once adjusted for noise, as a function of elevation from the channel bed. Dataset: $\boldsymbol{U_{0}}$ = 0.58 m/s; measurement location = (5, 0, $z$); ADV sampling period per coordinate = 5 min.}
\label{tab:noise_floor_as_a_function_elevation_0211-0215}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}*{7}{p{.111\textwidth}}@{}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{z [m]}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Noise standard deviation [ms$^{-1}$]}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variance reduction due to noise [\%]} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & $u$ & $v$ & $w$ & $u$ & $v$ & $w$ \\
\midrule
0.400   & 9.7e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 53.2  &   77.8  &  20.5  \\
0.300   & 1.1e$^{-2}$  & 1.1e$^{-2}$   & 2.5e$^{-3}$   & 63.9  &   84.1  &  27.9  \\
0.200   & 9.3e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.1e$^{-3}$   & 59.9  &   83.8  &  24.2  \\
0.100   & 9.5e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.1e$^{-3}$   & 59.0  &   76.5  &  20.9  \\
0     & 9.9e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 60.6  &   80.0  &  21.4  \\
-0.100  & 9.3e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.1e$^{-3}$   & 53.3  &   78.0  &  19.9  \\
-0.200  & 9.6e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 50.3  &   73.4  &  16.8  \\
-0.300  & 9.9e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 51.5  &   59.8  &  13.6  \\
-0.385  & 9.7e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 53.2  &   66.0  &  16.8  \\
\botrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The columns will look better centred, but this will require the `array` package (with an up-to-date array package, one could simplify this by using `w{c}{.111\textwidth}`, but if you are submitting to a journal, I would not bet on an up-to-date array package, but the manual approach shown below should not cause a problem, you are loading much more problematic packages than `array`)

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{program}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\caption{Estimates of the noise standard deviation, and the corresponding reduction in velocity variance, once adjusted for noise, as a function of elevation from the channel bed. Dataset: $\boldsymbol{U_{0}}$ = 0.58 m/s; measurement location = (5, 0, $z$); ADV sampling period per coordinate = 5 min.}
\label{tab:noise_floor_as_a_function_elevation_0211-0215}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}*{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.111\textwidth}}@{}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{z [m]}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Noise standard deviation [ms$^{-1}$]}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variance reduction due to noise [\%]} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & $u$ & $v$ & $w$ & $u$ & $v$ & $w$ \\
\midrule
0.400   & 9.7e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 53.2  &   77.8  &  20.5  \\
0.300   & 1.1e$^{-2}$  & 1.1e$^{-2}$   & 2.5e$^{-3}$   & 63.9  &   84.1  &  27.9  \\
0.200   & 9.3e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.1e$^{-3}$   & 59.9  &   83.8  &  24.2  \\
0.100   & 9.5e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.1e$^{-3}$   & 59.0  &   76.5  &  20.9  \\
0     & 9.9e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 60.6  &   80.0  &  21.4  \\
-0.100  & 9.3e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.1e$^{-3}$   & 53.3  &   78.0  &  19.9  \\
-0.200  & 9.6e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 50.3  &   73.4  &  16.8  \\
-0.300  & 9.9e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 51.5  &   59.8  &  13.6  \\
-0.385  & 9.7e$^{-3}$  & 1.0e$^{-2}$   & 2.2e$^{-3}$   & 53.2  &   66.0  &  16.8  \\
\botrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you kindly, this has solved my problem. One last thing, how would I convert the number format in the 2nd - 4th columns to y x 10^{-z), as opposed to the current format, which I have?

Comment: @eg0u30a2 If you have a new question, you should ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

You're loading packages, even more than needed: `algorithmicx` and `algpseudocode` are fighting each other; `subcaption` is not compatible with the used class.

Load also `siunitx` and compute a suitable width.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{textcomp} % no longer needed
\usepackage{manyfoot} % do you need it?
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{program} % already loaded by the class, unfortunately
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{output-exponent-marker = \mathrm{e}}
\newlength{\tempwd}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Estimates of the noise standard deviation, and the corresponding 
reduction in velocity variance, once adjusted for noise, as a function of 
elevation from the channel bed. Dataset: $\bm{U}_{0}$ = \qty{0.58}{m/s}; 
measurement location = $(5, 0, z)$; ADV sampling period per coordinate = \qty{5}{min}}
\label{tab:noise_floor_as_a_function_elevation_0211-0215}

\settowidth{\tempwd}{\num{-0.400}}
\setlength{\tempwd}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-1em-\tempwd)/6}
\newcommand{\?}[1]{{\makebox[\tempwd]{#1}}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=-1.3]
  @{\quad}
  *{3}{S[table-format=1.1e-1]}
  *{3}{S[table-format=2.1]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
{z[m]}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Noise standard deviation (\unit{ms^{-1}})}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Variance reduction due to noise (\%)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & \?{$u$} & \?{$v$} & \?{$w$} & \?{$u$} & \?{$v$} & \?{$w$} \\
\midrule
 0.400   & 9.7e-3  & 1.0e-2   & 2.2e-3   & 53.2  &   77.8  &  20.5  \\
 0.300   & 1.1e-2  & 1.1e-2   & 2.5e-3   & 63.9  &   84.1  &  27.9  \\
 0.200   & 9.3e-3  & 1.0e-2   & 2.1e-3   & 59.9  &   83.8  &  24.2  \\
 0.100   & 9.5e-3  & 1.0e-2   & 2.1e-3   & 59.0  &   76.5  &  20.9  \\
 0       & 9.9e-3  & 1.0e-2   & 2.2e-3   & 60.6  &   80.0  &  21.4  \\
-0.100   & 9.3e-3  & 1.0e-2   & 2.1e-3   & 53.3  &   78.0  &  19.9  \\
-0.200   & 9.6e-3  & 1.0e-2   & 2.2e-3   & 50.3  &   73.4  &  16.8  \\
-0.300   & 9.9e-3  & 1.0e-2   & 2.2e-3   & 51.5  &   59.8  &  13.6  \\
-0.385   & 9.7e-3  & 1.0e-2   & 2.2e-3   & 53.2  &   66.0  &  16.8  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I define a local command for the column headers, so they fix the common width of the columns.

Comment: thanks for this. The packages are pre-defined in the journal template, and they can quite funny about adding and modifying the package list. I opted for the solution posted by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz as it was more non-invasive.